# why can't i log into phpmyadmin through localhost?

Tags: error-handling, phpmyadmin, xampp

I created an Html file linking a php file and the first time i logged into phpmyadmin after installing xampp successfully. After making a database in phpmyadmin i tried to load the webpage through localhost but can't load the page resulting in an error message. After that i tried to go back to the phpmyadmin but that's also not loading anymore. What could be causing this?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RKHo.png)

How should fix this? what are the things i should try?